# visualization LineChart to display yearly progress

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I have Created yearly progress chart using visualization **LineChart** but i face display issue.

**Ex-**

```
Year 2011 - got 250 points
Year 2012 - got 260 points
Year 2013 - got 280 points
Year 2014 - got 270 points till Month of October.
```

**Due to current year is not completed my points are less than the previous year.That's why chart display down progress for this year.**

How to resolve this issue?